# Frameloss on iOS13 -> unusable recordings

Tags: objective-c, core-audio, ios13, audiotoolbox

my App is recording audio with `kAudioFormatLinearPCM` set up in der `AudioStreamBasicDescription`. It all works fine on iOS12 (checked by downloading the container). After updating to iOS13 the audio file is saved correctly but when reopening the file, a wrong frame count is returned.The audio is unusable.

We are using a mix of swift and objective c code.

My `AudioStreamBasicDescription`:

```swift
self.audioFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription(
            mSampleRate:        Double(self.hardwareSampleRate),
            mFormatID:          kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
            mFormatFlags:       ( kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked ),
            mBytesPerPacket:    4,
            mFramesPerPacket:   1,
            mBytesPerFrame:     4,
            mChannelsPerFrame:  1,
            mBitsPerChannel:    32,
            mReserved:          0
        );
self.audioPlot = XOAudioPlotGL();
self.audioPlot.initialize(withSourceAudioFormat: self.audioFormat);
```

hardwareSampleReate = 44100

And reopening the file:

```
CheckError(ExtAudioFileOpenURL(readURL, &mAudioFileRef), "Error: Open File");
CheckError(ExtAudioFileSetProperty(mAudioFileRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(audioFormat), &audioFormat), "Set Client Data Format");
CFRelease(readURL);

UInt32 propSize = sizeof(SInt64);
UInt32 numberOfFrames = 0;
CheckError(ExtAudioFileGetProperty(mAudioFileRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames, &propSize, &numberOfFrames), "Get Number of Frames");
```

Here a lower framenumber is returned.

I don't see a reason why this all would work on iOS12 but not on iOS13.

Please let me know if I missed something or more details are needed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you know the frame number is wrong?  Why can't you use the returned frame number?

Comment: I checked the frame number the file was saved with the one when opening the file. When opening the frame number is more than 50% under the one when saving the file. Also checked with iOS12. There I got both time the same number of frames.